# CodeIgniter Testing the Base URL

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have downloaded and unzipped CodeIgniter 3.0.4

I have copied the files to C:\xampp\htdocs\myfirstciproj

"myfirstciproj" is the folder where I have the index.php

I have edited the config file as follows -

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myfirstciproj/';
```

Now, my question is, how do I test whether CodeIgniter is correctly taking the base URL?

Comment: You can check `APPPATH . 'config/routes.php'` file and see what is default controller set or change it to some more appropriate.

Comment: check with `var_dump()`  eg: `var_dump(base_url());`